# How can I change the device on which OpenCL-code will be executed with Umat in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, opencl, x86-64, opencv3.0

As known, OpenCV 3.0 supports new class [`cv::Umat`](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d45/classcv_1_1UMat.html#gsc.tab=0) which provides Transparent API (TAPI) to use OpenCL automaticaly if it can: http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/Opencv3#tapi

There are two introductions to the `cv::Umat` and TAPI:

- Intel: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencv-30-architecture-guide-for-intel-inde-opencv
- AMD: http://developer.amd.com/community/blog/2014/10/15/opencv-3-0-transparent-api-opencl-acceleration/

But if I have:

1. Intel CPU Core i5 (Haswell) 4xCores (OpenCL [Intel CPUs with SSE 4.1, SSE 4.2 or AVX support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL#Conformant_products))
2. Intel Integrated HD Graphics which [supports OpenCL 1.2](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-033757.htm)
3. 1st nVidia GPU GeForce GTX 970 (Maxwell) which [supports OpenCL 1.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Nvidia_graphics_processing_units#GeForce_900_Series)
   and CUDA
4. 2nd nVidia GPU GeForce GTX 970 ...

If I turn on OpenCL in OpenCV, then how can I change the device on which OpenCL-code will be executed: on 8 Cores of CPU, on Integrated HD Graphics, on 1st nVidia GPU or 2nd nVidia GPU?

How can I select one of each of these 4 devices to use OpenCL for parallel execution algorithms with `cv::Umat`?

For example, how can I use OpenCL acceleration on 4xCores of CPU Core-i5 with `cv::Umat`?

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ocl/doc/introduction.html "Also the user can use cv::ocl::setDevice function (with cv::ocl::getOpenCLPlatforms and cv::ocl::getOpenCLDevices). This function initializes OpenCL runtime and setup the passed device as computing device."

Comment: @DarkZeros  Thank you! Yes, it might be work on OpenCV 2.4.12, but **`cv::ocl::setDevice` is not in OpenCV 3.0** where appeared `cv:Umat`. There are namespace `ocl` http://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/d96/namespacecv_1_1ocl.html#gsc.tab=0 also `class Device` with `enum`-s `TYPE_` and `VENDOR_` http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d9f/classcv_1_1ocl_1_1Device.html#gsc.tab=0 and functions `attachContext()`/`initializeContextFromHandle()`. But there are not function to set global variable to use required `Device`. How can I set `Device` for whole program, or this thread, or this `cv::Umat` in OpenCV3.0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use something like this to check versions and hardware being used for OpenCL support.

```
ocl::setUseOpenCL(true);
if (!ocl::haveOpenCL())
{
    cout << "OpenCL is not available..." << endl;
    //return;
}

cv::ocl::Context context;
if (!context.create(cv::ocl::Device::TYPE_GPU))
{
    cout << "Failed creating the context..." << endl;
    //return;
}

cout << context.ndevices() << " GPU devices are detected." << endl; //This bit provides an overview of the OpenCL devices you have in your computer
for (int i = 0; i < context.ndevices(); i++)
{
    cv::ocl::Device device = context.device(i);
    cout << "name:              " << device.name() << endl;
    cout << "available:         " << device.available() << endl;
    cout << "imageSupport:      " << device.imageSupport() << endl;
    cout << "OpenCL_C_Version:  " << device.OpenCL_C_Version() << endl;
    cout << endl;
}
```

Then you can set your preferred hardware to use, using this

```
cv::ocl::Device(context.device(1));
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for. `cv::ocl::Device(context.device(1));` - Does it have an effect on the whole program, or only the current thread as `gpu::setDevice(i)` in OpenCV2.4? I.e. in the loop `for (int i = 0; i < context.ndevices(); i++) {  cv::ocl::Device device = context.device(i); } ` I can compare each `device.vendorID()` with `enum   { 
  UNKNOWN_VENDOR =0, 
  VENDOR_AMD =1, 
  VENDOR_INTEL =2, 
  VENDOR_NVIDIA =3 
}` and find only required, and then get its name as cv::String by `device.vendorName()`. And use `cv::ocl::Device(context.device(i));` for each thread.

Comment: I set cv::ocl::Device(context.device(1)) because i have Nvidia GT520M which supports OpenCL1.1 but my integrated Intel HD Graphics 3000 doesn't support OpenCL. Yes it has effect in the whole program because you have to set it to your preffered graphics card to use for OpenCL.

Comment: I.e. so I can't use 2 x nVidia GPUs each from other CPU-thread? Or somehow can I set the OCL context only for current CPU-thread, without affect to other CPU-threads as in CUDA?

Comment: Well...i am not sure which threading technique you are using. You can try calling 2 GPU's in different threads and see if it works. I guess you have to change the Context of GPU in the code every time you want to change the access to a different GPU.I usually use Qt threading or boost threading because i can wait for the thread to finish its job and merge it with the master thread. Not so sure about this idea. But let me know if it works.

Comment: Can I force once algorithm to run on CPU and another on GPU?

Comment: anyone know how to set within python? i wish to use  OpenCV DNN(OpenCL) in python module .....

Comment: @MarKS Your answer has generally become the only thing one can find on the internet regarding this issue. However, I don't understand which mechanism should the statement `cv::ocl::Device(context.device(1));` use to change anything. This statement is just a call to the copy-constructor of Device. It is not even a function call per se - just constructing a temporary object through its copy constructor and throwing it right away. I checked the source code and no constructor of Device should have any side-effects. So what is the mechanism this call would use to change the current device?

Comment: @MartinPecka I might be wrong. But the call is not only to copy-constructor but a call to device() function from the current context. I think the index passed in the device function sets which device to use, in case, you have multiple devices (as listed by for loop) which support OpenCL.

Comment: @MarKS You're right there's also the `device()` function call. But that's just a getter, no side-effects: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/70bbf17b133496bd7d54d034b0f94bd869e0e810/modules/core/src/ocl.cpp#L2837 .

Answer (score 3):

You can also set a desired OpenCL device from within your code using environment variable method as follows (example is first GPU device):

```
if (putenv("OPENCV_OPENCL_DEVICE=:GPU:0") != 0 || !cv::ocl::useOpenCL())
{
    std::cerr << "Failed to set a desired OpenCL device" << std::endl;
    std::cerr << "Press any key to exit..." << std::endl;
    getchar();
    return 1;
}
```

Call to cv::ocl::useOpenCL() will force OpenCV to setup a default OpenCL device to the one specified in the environment variable OPENCV_OPENCL_DEVICE which is setup prior to that call.

I checked that this actually happens by setting a break-point at opencv_core310d.dll!cv::ocl::selectOpenCLDevice() Line 2256 (opencv\source\modules\core\src\ocl.cpp):

```
static cl_device_id selectOpenCLDevice()
{
    std::string platform, deviceName;
    std::vector<std::string> deviceTypes;

    const char* configuration = getenv("OPENCV_OPENCL_DEVICE");
    if (configuration &&
            (strcmp(configuration, "disabled") == 0 ||
             !parseOpenCLDeviceConfiguration(std::string(configuration), platform, deviceTypes, deviceName)
            ))
        return NULL;
```