# How to use OpenCL version of SURF?

Tags: c++, opencv, opencl, opencv3.0, feature-detection

I use the following code for feature detection:

```cpp
auto detector = cv::xfeatures2d::SURF::create();
std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints;

for (const cv::Mat& image : images) {
    detector->detect(image, keypoints);
    process(keypoints);
}
```

Now I try to use OpenCL version of SURF. I modified my code to work with `cv::UMat`. Unfortunately, execution time does not change. `HAS_OPENCL` is set, `cv::ocl::useOpenCL()` is true. What could go wrong?

Comment: did you find  http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/nonfree/doc/feature_detection.html#ocl-surf-ocl and http://code.opencv.org/attachments/1560/surf.ocl.cpp ??

Comment: @Micka Unfortunately, this relates to OpenCL 2.4, not 3.0. `SURF_OCL` doesn't even exist there.

Comment: Did you try calling `cv::ocl::setUseOpenCL(true);` explicitly? But http://answers.opencv.org/question/63452/opencv-30-the-performance-of-umat/ says that there might be many functions that weren's converted to the new api, so probably the/many non-free functions belong to them.

Comment: is it possible to check the OCL device? Maybe you have got multiple devices and a slow one is selected?

Comment: did you find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33417451/how-can-i-change-the-device-on-wich-opencl-code-will-be-executed-with-umat-in-op ?

Comment: @Micka It is possible, but unfortunately, I've already moved to using `SURF_CUDA` :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that I'm a little bit late for this, but looking at [`surf.cpp`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/246ea8f3bdf174a2aad6216c2601e3a93bf75c29/modules/xfeatures2d/src/surf.cpp), 
 `SURF_Impl::detectAndCompute` starts with a `#ifdef HAVE_OPENCL`, so I think that if you built OpenCV with OpenCL enabled, OpenCL is used by default

Comment: Okay, but then it means that OpenCL implementation was 10 times slower than CUDA on my computer. Seems strange to me.

Comment: @Anton3 just as info: which CUDA SURF implementation are you using? How long does it take for you on avg to describe only **one** image using GPU approach? Please if possible specify also the image size and the used GPU

Comment: I use SURF_CUDA from OpenCV. It takes about 0.2 seconds with SURF_CUDA and about 2 seconds with normal SURF class. Image size is 1920x1080, GPU is GTX 970. Edit: well, it took, because I did the tests half a year ago.