# Fail to use OpenCL in OpenCV 3.2

Tags: c++, opencv, opencl

I want to use OpenCL to accelerate my OpenCV program, so I try to use OpenCV's transparent API.

**System info**

- OpenCV 3.2.0
- NVIDIA GTX 760 with CUDA Toolkit 8.0
- Windows 10 64-bit
- Visual Studio 2015

**Problem description**

When I try to use the transparent API cv::UMat, it is fine. But I find the executing time is longer than simply using Mat.

Then I find out the `ocl::haveOpenCL()` return **false**, and `ocl::getPlatfomsInfo(platforms)` throw error message error: **(-220) OpenCL function is not available: [clGetPlatformIDs] in function opencl_check_fn**

**Code snippet**

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/ocl.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ocl::setUseOpenCL(true);

    vector<ocl::PlatformInfo> platforms;
    try {
        ocl::getPlatfomsInfo(platforms);
    }
    catch (cv::Exception& e)
    {
        const char* err_msg = e.what();
        std::cout << "exception caught: " << err_msg << std::endl;
    }

    if (!ocl::haveOpenCL()) {
        std::cout << "OpenCL is not available..." << std::endl;
    }

    std::clock_t start;
    double duration;

    UMat uimg,ugray;
    imread("test.jpg", 1).copyTo(uimg);
    start = std::clock();
    cvtColor(uimg, ugray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    GaussianBlur(ugray, ugray, Size(7, 7), 1.5);
    Canny(ugray, ugray, 0, 50);
    duration = (std::clock() - start) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    Mat ugray_r = ugray.getMat(ACCESS_RW);

    Mat img, gray;
    img = imread("test.jpg", 1);
    start = std::clock();
    cvtColor(img, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    GaussianBlur(gray, gray, Size(7, 7), 1.5);
    Canny(gray, gray, 0, 50);
    duration = (std::clock() - start) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    imshow("edges", gray);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

I think there might be something wrong with my environment or OpenCV build. But the `OpenCL.dll` and `OpenCL64.dll` can be found under CUDA Toolkit directory. Can anyone give me any suggestions about what do I have to check?

BTW, I find very few detail information of using OpenCL in OpenCV 3, any useful info about how to build, configure or use OpenCL in OpenCV is appreciated.

Comment: I don't know what OpenCV requires but NVidia cards (deliberately it seems) have very basic OpenCL support see https://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-gtx-760m/specifications this shows that this card only supports OpenCL 1.1 which may not be enough. Seeing as you are using OpenCV I'd use the CUDA version which has better support in OpenCV from my experience

Comment: thanks @EdChum, I did have tried cuda before. But I need my application to be able to run on different devices. My current problem is that I even cannot use OpenCL here, I want to first have a try and then decide whether to use it that much.

Comment: For that I'd suggest having code that test whether you have a card with CUDA capability, if so execute that code, another test for openCL, if so execute that code and failing all that, do it in CPU

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea, but with OpenCV's transparent API support, I would first try to do an OpenCL version then a CUDA version.

Comment: Seriously you need to write code for all platforms you intend to support to cover these situations, this is what I do I write code for CUDA support and CPU, openCL support in OpenCV is not that great, there are far more algorithms implemented in CUDA than OpenCL

Comment: If your onboard graphics supports OpenCL, then maybe detecting the device which supports OpenCL might help you. If successful you can try setting it as your default devic. Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33417451/how-can-i-change-the-device-on-wich-opencl-code-will-be-executed-with-umat-in-op/34250412#34250412

Comment: @MarKS thank you but I currently have `ocl::haveOpenCL()` return `false`